# Съезжает верстка кнопки на странице профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

На странице профиля (при залогиненом юзере) съезжает верстка кнопки из-за длинного текста. Открывал в Google Chrome. Решить можно путем добавления display: block в стиле элемента

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]